# from a sparse file to a block device over the network

Tags: linux, ssh, rsync, dd, sparse-files

If I have a sparse file representing a block device, then how can I efficiently restore the file over a network?  Ideally, I'd use `rsync -S host:file /dev/sdb`, but `rsync` won't write to block devices.  I am using `ssh host dd if=file | dd of=/dev/sdb`, but that's not efficient as the zero bytes will come over the network and be written to the device.  Can I use `tar -S` or `cp --sparse=always` somehow?  Can I do this without storing the file locally (even temporarily)?  Can sshfs recognise sparse files?

Answer (score 3):

I haven't tested it, but there is a `write-devices` patch to rsync, which would solve your problem. You can find the patch in the [rsync-patches](http://gitweb.samba.org/?p=rsync-patches.git;a=tree) repository.

Answer (score 2):

You can install the [iSCSI Enterprise Target](http://iscsitarget.sourceforge.net/) software and setup an iSCSI LUN from the sparse-file like so:

In /etc/iet/ietd.conf:

```
Target iqn.my.iscsi.test:disk1
        Lun 0 Path=/path/to/my/sparse_file,Type=fileio
```

Then initiate the target from the host you need to restore on. Since the target will show as a local device (eg. /dev/sdd), you can `dd` from that device to your local device.

Comment: How is this more efficient then what I have now?  Once I use dd, won't it read and write the zero bytes?

Comment: No more hassle from "middle man" programs.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried compressing/decompressing the data in flight? Batches of zeroes should compress well.

Actually, having thought about it again, it's very simple. On the remote host, create a pipe with `mkfifo`. `scp`/`dd` to that pipe as usual and `cp --sparse=always` from it to the actual target file.

Tested on my installation and it does produce a sparse file on output. Thanks for a nice question!

Comment: ssh will compress for me.  that's not the issue.